# How to convert JSON into dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, census

Any ideas on how to transform this JSON file into a usable dataframe format:

```
pd.read_json("http://api.census.gov/data/2014/acsse/variables.json")
```

Here's how the table should look: http://api.census.gov/data/2014/acsse/variables.html

Comment: This doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you start with

```
df = pd.read_json("http://api.census.gov/data/2014/acsse/variables.json")
```

The problem is that the column is of dicts:

```
In [28]: df.variables.head()
Out[28]: 
AIANHH    {u'concept': u'Selectable Geographies', u'pred...
ANRC      {u'concept': u'Selectable Geographies', u'pred...
BST       {u'concept': u'Selectable Geographies', u'pred...
CBSA      {u'concept': u'Selectable Geographies', u'pred...
CD        {u'concept': u'Selectable Geographies', u'pred...
Name: variables, dtype: object
```

But you can solve this by applying a `Series`:

```
In [27]: df.variables.apply(pd.Series)
Out[27]: 
                                                         concept  \
AIANHH                                    Selectable Geographies   
ANRC                                      Selectable Geographies   
BST                                       Selectable Geographies   
CBSA                                      Selectable Geographies   
CD                                        Selectable Geographies   
CNECTA                                    Selectable Geographies   
...
```

This is the DataFrame you want, probably, as can be shown by:

```
In [32]: df.variables.apply(pd.Series).columns
Out[32]: Index([u'concept', u'label', u'predicateOnly', u'predicateType'], dtype='object')
```